# How can I add an option with a checkbox to add an additional fee to a product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a bit of a specific need to fill here. My client sales tennis lessons. He wants to be able to have an option on the form that I have created (Gravity Forms) that allows a customer to select a box that allows an additional student for the class. Not only does it allow the additional student, but it needs to charge an extra $10.00 for said student and have the availability to increment the number of students. Currently I have it set up like [this](http://www.yourcourttennis.com/shop/shop-2/schedule-an-appointment/) (look towards the bottom) I would like to simplify it to have just the one check box and the increment number box as I already have on the site. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Product addons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) or maybe [gravity forms addons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am already using product add ons and that is how I have it implemented currently. Just wondering if there is an easier way to do it where it looks more simple. :)

Comment: I see what you mean now. The way you have it is pretty complex. Could you make the different options variations of a variable product? Then you should only need to add "extra adults" or "extra kids".

Comment: I could do that, but then how would I be able to increment how many students they would like to bring. See my dilemma?

Comment: Maybe via quantity and [dynamic pricing(http://www.woothemes.com/products/dynamic-pricing/)? Can add-ons not multiply a price by a quantity and add that? It has been a while since I have used addons so I don't recall.